# set navigationController's rootViewController as delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

My problem may be one of technique instead of a misunderstanding of how controllers and delegates are set up.  That is, maybe I should be doing all a different way...

In any event, I have a storyboard setup with a mainViewController.  In it there's a `UIButton` which, when clicked, segues to a popover.  The popover's content view controller is a `UINavigationController` who's `rootViewController` is, say, `MyViewController`.

I'm trying to make the `mainViewController` a `delegate` of `MyViewController` and am doing so in prepareForSegue:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:(@"popSleepSegue")] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:(@"popAlarmSegue")])
    {
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        popSegue.popoverController.delegate = self;
        popSegue.popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.view];
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popAlarmSegue"])
        {
            if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            {
                UINavigationController *uNC = (UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController];
                MyViewController *aVC = (MyViewController *)uNC.topViewController;
                aVC.popController = popSegue.popoverController;
                aVC.delegate = self;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `[self.delegate class]` is coming up as `null` in an `NSLog` when `MyViewController` loads.  And, naturally, the `delegate` callback isn't received in the `mainViewController`.

Essentially, I'm trying to mimic the behavior of Apple's Calendar app on the iPad.

I'm trying to use delegation to pass data upstream as per the idiom.  The trick is that I'm trying to set the `delegate` through a `UINavigationController` which is the content view of a popover.  Sounds too complex.  Maybe there's another idiom?

In the meantime, I'm going to give NSNotificationCenter a whirl.

Comment: Strangely enough, while I'm getting `null` here: `[self.delegate class]` in MyViewController's viewDidLoad the callback is actually getting triggered.  Strange.

Comment: I just created a test variable in MyViewController: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *testString;` and am trying to set that in the segue and print it out in MyViewController's view did load.  Didn't work.  My guess is that MyViewController doesn't exist at the time of segue - that the UINavigationController (i.e. the destination view controller) is the only one that exists.  Hmm.

Comment: Goodness gracious - if I move the NSLog printout of the [self.delegate class] (and the testString) from viewDidLoad to right before I call the delegate protocol, then they do indeed print out correctly, showing that the delegate (and testString) were indeed set in prepareForSegue.  Any ideas?  Are @properties not set until _after_ viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1):

You have to potential 'if' statements which can not be true:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popAlarmSegue"])
        {
            if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            {
```

From the look of your code, you should get the controller drilling inside the content controller in the PopOver,not the destination viewController from the segue. As it seems the second 'if' is not true.

You would need to add:

```
            if ([[popSegue.popoverController contentViewController] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            {
                UINavigationController *uNC = (UINavigationController *)popSegue.popoverController;
                MyViewController *aVC = (MyViewController *)uNC.topViewController;
                aVC.popController = popSegue.popoverController;
                aVC.delegate = self;
            }
```

Comment: Why can both of those 'if' statements not be true?  One is talking about the segue's identifier, while the other is talking about the destination view controller's class?  Those are two separate things.  FYI, I don't, in fact, need the 2nd one because I _know_ that it has to be a UINavigationController but I'm checking for thoroughness.

Comment: I should mention that I get the same results if I use your code or mine.  I see the logic behind using `contentViewController` but for some reason it's not changing anything.

Comment: Also, if you look at my comments to the question, I'm getting the expected results if I wait until after viewDidLoad finishes before NSLogging.

Comment: By means of using a breakpoint, does the code reach the innermost if? I suppose yes, so then you would need to see if the 'aVC' pointer value (in hex) is the same as 'self' in viewDidLoad of MyController. I only see that delegate is set in different controller. Order of callbacks is prepareForSegue -> ViewDidLoad -> ViewWillAppear -> ...